# Displaying only 2 lines of text in LyX Editor

Tags: lyx-layouts

Lets say I type a LyX document, that after 5 minutes of writing looks like this:

[image]

Now the bottom line is the line I am continuing to wrote on, this I have already written enough text to cover the whole displayable area. But it is tiring to always see everything I have written so far, since at times I would like to only concentrate on what I'm writing NOW, so only so bottom line and - at most - the line above the bottom line are of interest. But there is no way to scroll down the document, like in Word or any primitve text editor, to see just those lines, like this:
[image]

Does anybody know, if this can be achieved in LyX ? Even if the bottom line of the text would be displayed at the middle of the page would be a great improvement.

P.S. Yes, I know, I have somewhat heavily edited the appearance of my LyX editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a checkbox in the preferences that will enable you to scroll below the end of the document:

Tools ⇒ Preferences ⇒ Editing ⇒ Control ⇒ check *Scroll below end of document*

[image]